# How to tell python HTMLParser to stop

Tags: python, dns, html-parsing

I have a use case telling that when a tag is `link` and it's attributes are `rel=dns-prefetch` then just say that pre resolving dns is enabled.

I have made a flag as `pre_resolve_dns_enabled` and set it to true as follows.

```
class Extractor(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.pre_resolve_dns_enabled = False

    def feed(self, data):
        HTMLParser.feed(self,data)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'link' and ('rel', 'dns-prefetch') in attrs:
            self.pre_resolve_dns_enabled = True
            #Now if one dns is resolved so whole domain remains resolved , how do I tell the parser to abort now , leaving the flag to true.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTMLParser is not designed to be stopped. For that you want to use a streaming parser like `xml.sax` or `xml.etree.cElementTree`.

Is it really a problem to digest the entire HTML file? The expected use case goes like:

```
extractor = Extractor()
... feed html to extractor using one or more .feed() calls ...
extractor.close()

if extractor.pre_resolved_dns_enabled:
  ...
else:
  ...
```

If it really is a problem you can break up the input HTML into chunks and feed them until you find your tag, e.g.:

```
html = ...the html to parse...
chunks = [ html[i:i+1024] for i in xrange(0, len(html), 1024) ]
extractor = Extractor()
for c in chunks:
  if extractor.pre_resolved_dns_enabled:
    break
  extractor.feed(c)
extractor.close()
# check extractor.pre_resolved_dns_enabled
```